# Update a SharePoint list with Elevated Privileges without changing Modified By field data

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Is it possible to update a sharepoint list with elevated privileges while maintaining the actual user details for created by and modified by.  I've tried to manually add these values with the correct user account but they seem to be overwritten by the System Account value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean updating items in the list? If so try [SystemUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx)

> Updates the database with changes made to the list item without changing the Modified or Modified By fields.

Comment: Urgh, I was sure that SystemUpdate was only for avoiding triggering workflows and events as side effects. You're right - the docs say it won't change the modified by field. This is horrible - what use is auditing?

Comment: I guess if your solution requires strict auditting then you'd steer clear of any code calling SystemUpdate(). Also, I'm pretty sure SystemUpdate still triggers events and workflows.

Comment: I tried this and it maintained the old user on the created by field but not the last modified.  Also, I can't seem to get this working for a new item ...  any ideas?

Comment: When creating the new list items are you creating it manually (in the browser) or programmatically? Are you using event receivers? If so which events?

Comment: Programmattically using the SPList Update method.  If i change to SystemUpdate and manually set the Author and Editor items it seems to get overridden by the System Account value.

Comment: Are you adding the item whilst elevating priviledges? If so that's why it's going in as the system account. You could move the code that adds the item before you elevate the priviledges and then make the changes within it. This means the list item will be initially created by the logged on user and the updates to the values/fields will be done by the system account. When updating, call SystemUpdate and it will look like the item was created with the values originally. Make sense?